Chroma from_documents Crashes with Exit Code -1073741819 (0xC0000005) Without Error Message
I'm working with LangChain and Chroma to perform embeddings on a DataFrame. My DataFrame shape is (1350, 10), and the code for embedding is as follows:
def embed_with_chroma(persist_directory=r'./vector_db/',
                      db_directory=r'./sql/sop_database.sqlite',
                      collection_name='sop_vectorstore',
                      batch_size=200):
    """
    Reads all data from an SQLite database, converts it to embeddings, and saves to disk in batches.
    """
    # Initialize the embedding model
    embedding_model = HuggingFaceEmbeddings(model_name="source_data/BAAI",
                                            model_kwargs={'device': 'cpu'})

    # Query to get all data
    query = """
    SELECT m.model_name AS "model", m.brand AS "brand", m.product_line AS "product_line", g.group_name AS "group", s.step_name AS "step", s.detail
    FROM Steps s
    JOIN Groups g ON s.group_id = g.group_id
    JOIN Models m ON g.model_id = m.model_id
    ORDER BY m.model_name, g.group_name, s.step_id;
    """
    conn = sqlite3.connect(db_directory)
    df = pd.read_sql_query(query, conn)
    conn.close()

    # Prepare data in batches to manage memory usage
    vectorstore = None
    total_epochs = (len(df) // batch_size) + 1
    epoch = 1
    for start in range(0, len(df), batch_size):
        print(f'epoch {epoch}/{total_epochs}')
        batch_df = df.iloc[start:start + batch_size].copy()
        batch_df['merge'] = batch_df.apply(lambda row: f"Model: {row['model']}, Group: {row['group']}, Step: {row['step']}", axis=1)

        # Load documents and split into chunks
        loader = DataFrameLoader(batch_df, page_content_column='merge')
        documents = loader.load()
        text_splitter = CharacterTextSplitter(chunk_size=512, chunk_overlap=128)
        documents_chunks = text_splitter.split_documents(documents)

        # Initialize or append to vectorstore
        if vectorstore is None:
            vectorstore = Chroma.from_documents(documents_chunks,
                                                embedding_model,
                                                collection_name=collection_name,
                                                persist_directory=persist_directory)
        else:
            vectorstore.add_documents(documents_chunks)

        # Free up memory
        del batch_df, loader, documents, documents_chunks
        gc.collect()
        epoch += 1

    return vectorstore

The code crashes when running Chroma.from_documents with the following error message:
Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)

I've tried adjusting memory and batch size, but the crash persists without additional error messages. Here are some details that may be relevant:

My environment has 8GB of RAM.
I’m using LangChain and Chroma for embeddings.
The DataFrame has 1350 rows and 10 columns.

Any insights on why this might be happening or how to debug this issue further would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you!

The root cause of this is HNSW lib which Chroma uses for vector storage/retrieval. It is has been reported by people for a few months now, here is an example - https://github.com/chroma-core/chroma/issues/2513.
The reason why this problem appears when you add 1350 vectors as opposed to 100 is due to how Chroma internally updates HNSW. Chroma has an configuration called hnsw:sync_treshold that controls at how many embeddings Chroma will flush data to HNSW (it's called dirty persist and only stored the changed embeddings). Here's a link to a more in-depth overview
The issue is more pronounced on Windows systems than on any other OS. Right now the candidate problem domain is pybind11, but it has not been 100% proven that this is the case. The team is still investigating.
The workarounds that people have found working are:

Use Chroma as server e.g. run it in Docker
Apply windows patches
Update python to the latest release (e.g. if you use 3.10 - 3.10.16 is the latest)
Change the python version e.g. use 3.11 or 3.12

